# Назовите,(?) в чем заключается...

Tags: запятая

Назовите,(?) в чем заключается...
Нужна ли запятая или нет?

Answer (score 3):

Нужна, это сложноподчинённое предложение.Главное - "Назовите", зависимое-"в чём заключается..."